# Equivalent of numpy.linalg.norm for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

After searching a while, I could not find a function to compute the l2 norm of a tensor. It seems really strange for me that it's not included so I'm probably missing something.

I looked at the `l2_normalize` and `tf.clip_by_norm` implementations and all use `rsqrt(reduce_sum(x**2))` to do the trick (in that case inverse norm).

I'm probably missing something or is there a reason for not including such common function as a standard operator ?

Edit: a relevant issue from one years ago: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/424

Comment: I guess no real reason other thatn there's not been a enough requests for it and nobody got to it. Numpy has 300 lines of test code for that function so fully mirroring it would take some work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added as `tf.norm(matrix, order="fro")` in commit [709fa61b](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/709fa61b)

Comment: Great :) . Thank you very much for the update (and your reactivity if you're the one who implemented it).

Comment: on ```tensorflow 2.x``` you have to use ```tf.norm(matrix, order="fro")```